# In regular expressions, how can an explicit character optionally appear in a replacement?

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract graph information from a text file and converting it to CSV format. The data appears in the format:

```
    X-axis    Y-axis    dY/dX
```

which I intend to convert to:

```
X-axis,Y-axis,dY/dX
```

It should be noted, however, that the `dY/dX` column is not always present when exported from the software being used.

The regular expression I have at present is:

```
\s*(?<xaxis>\-*\d+\.\d+)\s*(?<yaxis>\-*\d+\.\d+)\s*(?<dydx>\-*\d+\.\d+)*
```

and the replacement expression is:

```
${xaxis},${yaxis},${dydx}
```

My question is this: even though the matching expression accounts for the optional nature of the `dY/dX` column, how can the replacement expression do the same? At present, if the `dY/dX` column is not present, a trailing comma is printed to the CSV file. I appreciate this is not a major problem, but I would like to know if it is possible.

Comment: How about postprocessing the data and remove trailing commas?

Comment: Not an answer, but the last `*` should probably be `?` if there can't be more than one `dY/dX`.

Comment: how are you doing the replacement, in what language?

Comment: If you are passing the CSV to Excel, I don't think it cares whether the line ends with a trailing comma; in fact, it probably works better that way.

Comment: Excel actually likes it when all rows have the same number of columns (with as many empty fields as necessary to pad each row.) I've filed at least one bug against software that didn't expect dozens of trailing commas in Excel CSV files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to not be possible. I have since rewritten the program to store the data first in a `DataTable` instance, then generate a CSV file from that. That way, the number of columns can be determined and the necessary formatting applied to the output.